# Checkboxes appear in Playlists

Tags: itunes

How can I have the checkboxes appear by default in the playlists?  When I go to a playlist no checkboxes appear, so I can't see if the playlist will burn to a cd or not.
I am on a mac, OS 10.9.5 and the i-tunes is 12.2.1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you use the edit function to explain what OS is running iTunes and what version of the OS or the program? It could be PC, Mac, iOS and many many versions exist. It would be best to give the numeric versions since "latest" doesn't even mean much with all the beta versions of programs that are widely available.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about making it the default for ALL playlists, but at least to get the check boxes back in the current playlist you are working with, go to View>Show View Options, then change the "View As:" to Songs.

This worked for me, hope it helps someone else!